# Conflict with GSAP and Highcharts on the same page

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I have the jQuery.GSAP plugin plus the GSAP TweenMax and GSAP EasePack plugins running on the same page as Highcharts.

Example here (jQuery.GSAP is the issue): http://jsfiddle.net/danimt/m3cmk/

`jQuery.GSAP conflicts with the ongoing animation on Highcharts`

This makes the graphics buggy, as the animations are not executed, thus the scale getting weird when selecting/deselecting legends and column graphics don't even show up.

Is there a way to have them both playing nicely?

Comment: Could you recreate issue on jsFiddle? For me it looks right: http://jsfiddle.net/3bQne/484/

Comment: Added on the question ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I know, GSAP is overwriting jQuery.animate() function, so later Highcharts may use it in a wrong way - what can I advice is to use stand alone Highcharts version: http://jsfiddle.net/m3cmk/1/

```
new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
            renderTo:'container'
        },
        ... 
 });
```

And standalone version:

```
<script src="https://rawgithub.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/master/js/adapters/standalone-framework.src.js"></script>
```